# How to store the parsed JSON data in a singl array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have parsed JSON data the format of my JSON data is 
http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=categories&appid=620&mainonly=true"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to make a Book object and give it two properties: categoryId and name? So in the above json data you would have five different books?

Comment: i want that i get all the values by dictOne ok i want this store in an array so that i may fetch accorrding in a sequence if i show this data in table view so name and category id sould be fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a data modal?

```
@interface book:NSObject {
NSString *catId;
NSString *bookName
}

create properties for these two instance vars.
@end


@implementation book 

@synthesize catId,bookName;

- (id)init {
 self = [super init];
}

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary) dict {
 self.catId = [dict valueForKey:@"categoryId"];
  self.bookName = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[catId release];
[bookName release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end


and use it like this

 NSMutableArray *bookArray = [[NSmutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
 NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    for (int i=0; i<[results count]; i++) {
   book *bookObject = [[book alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
   [bookArray addObject:bookObject];
   [bookObject release];
}
```

Comment: it gives error can not parse object as parameter in - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary) dict {

Comment: try debugging your code or send me in mail. I have posted code only to give you some hint. my mail address is rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com let me know if you send the code in mail

Comment: thanks its working now i have another view controller in which i have to fetch in a same way but structure is different of JSON i want only date title location only from the JSON data i am posting the updated code in the question check that

Comment: i have posted url of json data which is to fetch in the same way as i fetched earlier

Comment: Sorry to say but You need to struggle further my dear. Stackoverflow is not for your homework. It's for your benefit otherwise you won't learn anything.

Comment: I have to ask that i am fetching data using same method for http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder this link using same data model but its giving error

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by way
Adding dictionary to array.

```
 for (NSDictionary *dict in mydict) {
            [myArray addObject:dict];
        }
```

You can do more modification and put the logic to set the values in array according 
to key as well.
Hope this may help you.Well I haven't checked it now.But may get you to the solution.

Cheers.....